# How to search entire XML file for keyword?

Tags: c#, xml, linq

Im learning C# and one of the things I am trying to do is read in an XML file and search it.

I have found a few examples where I can search specific nodes (if its a name or ISBN for example) for specific key words.

What I was looking to do was to search the entire XML file in order to find all possible matches of a keyword.

I know LIST allows a "contains" to find keywords, is there a similar function for searching an XML file?

Im using the generic books.xml file that is included when visual studio is installed.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Could you show us your code reading and searching xml?

Comment: Besides what are you expecting your keyword to be? An element ot its value, an attribute ot its value, etc... ??

Comment: Maybe you should consider it a text file and just do a simple search.

Answer (score 0):

For example, you could use [LINQ TO XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx). This example searches for the keyword both in elements and attributes - in their names and values.

```
private static IEnumerable<XElement> FindElements(string filename, string name)
{
    XElement x = XElement.Load(filename);
    return x.Descendants()
            .Where(e => e.Name.ToString().Equals(name) ||
                        e.Value.Equals(name) ||
                        e.Attributes().Any(a => a.Name.ToString().Equals(name) || 
                                                a.Value.Equals(name)));
}
```

and use it:

```
string s = "search value";
foreach (XElement x in FindElements("In.xml", s))
    Console.WriteLine(x.ToString());
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to search for keyword appear in leaf nodes' text, try the following
(using this sample [books.xml](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms762271.aspx)):

```
string keyword = "com";
var doc = XDocument.Load("books.xml");

var query = doc.Descendants()
    .Where(x => !x.HasElements &&
                x.Value.IndexOf(keyword, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0);
foreach (var element in query)
    Console.WriteLine(element);
```

Output:

```
<genre>Computer</genre>
<description>A former architect battles corporate zombies,
      an evil sorceress, and her own childhood to become queen
      of the world.</description>
<genre>Computer</genre>
<title>MSXML3: A Comprehensive Guide</title>
<genre>Computer</genre>
<title>Visual Studio 7: A Comprehensive Guide</title>
<genre>Computer</genre>
<description>Microsoft Visual Studio 7 is explored in depth,
      looking at how Visual Basic, Visual C++, C#, and ASP+ are
      integrated into a comprehensive development
      environment.</description>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a keyword that you already know, you can parse the XML just as simple text file and use StreamReader for parsing it. But if you are looking for an element in XML you can use XmlTextReader(), please consider this example:

```
using (XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(xmlPath))
{
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element)
        { 
            //do your code here
        }
    }
}
```

Hope it helps. :)