# LINQ/XML: Get the attribut value if the attribut name contains a certain key word

Tags: c#, xml, linq, xdoc

Since I am not very familiar with LINQ and xDocument, I struggle to implement the following:
I have a XML file which looks like

```
<document>
   <attribut1/>
   <attribut2>
      <house price="100" location="UK" id-ext="Id-100"/>
      <house price="300" location="GB" id-int="Id-101"/>
   </attribut2>
   <attribut3/>
</document>
```

Speaking in Pseudo Code I need something like

Input: xDocument

Output: List containing strings with all values, i.e. "Id-100" in this example, of those attributes where "id-ext" was included in the attribut name. Hence, I try to get the values of those attributes which contain some certain letters in their name.

I already searched for similar suggestions like the one stated here:
[How to search entire XML file for keyword?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12830714/how-to-search-entire-xml-file-for-keyword)
But the point is that here the whole XML-Node is returned and I don't manage to break it down to the name of an attribute.

I would appreciate any suggestions of how to move one after applying "Descendants" to get the values of those attributs where some keywords are contained in the attribut name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a dictionary

```
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);

            Dictionary<string, List<XElement>> dict = doc.Descendants("house")
                .Where(x => x.Attribute("id-ext") != null)
                .GroupBy(x => (string)x.Attribute("id-ext"))
                .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.ToList());
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming "keywords are contained in the attribut name" means that the attribute name as a string contains a specific substring, and that this attribute may occur on any element in the document:

```
var doc = XDocument.Parse(@"<document>
<attribut1/>
<attribut2>
   <house price='100' location='UK' id-ext='Id-100'/>
   <house price='300' location='GB' id-int='Id-101'/>
</attribut2>
<attribut3/>
</document>");

foreach (var s in doc
  .Descendants()
  .SelectMany(e => e.Attributes())
  .Where(a => a.Name.LocalName.Contains("id-ext"))
  .Select(a => a.Value))
{
    Console.WriteLine(s);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! :-) I really appreciate your suggestion since I do not have to specify the attribut name here.